# Python socket performance drops considerably when used in parallel

Tags: python, sockets, sftp

I use pretty much standard code to transfer a file from one node to another using Python/socket.

> Num-of-threads/Performance (comparing to sftp/scp)
>
> 1: 2x
>
> 2: 1.2x
>
> 3: 1x
>
> 4: 1x
>
> 5: 1x

It takes 25 sec to transfer 2.7G file over 10Gb network using Python/socket.
If I use fstp/scp it takes 50 sec to transfer the same file.

2 threads complete transfer in 47 sec sec using Python/socket script.
If I use fstp/scp it takes 55 sec to transfer the same 2 files in parallel.

3 threads transfer in 112 sec sec using Python/socket script.
fstp/scp does the same job in 112 sec (3 files in parallel).

Client code:

```
#client.py
import socket 
import sys
import datetime as dt
e=sys.exit
n1=dt.datetime.now()

#s = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0) 
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
#s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_CORK, 1)

host = 'testserver' 
port = %s            # Reserve a port for your service.
s.connect((host, port))

f = open('/tmp/testfile.gz','rb')
print 'Sending..',
l = f.read(1024*1024)
while (l):
  print '.',
  s.send(l)
  l = f.read(1024*1024)
f.close()
print "Done Sending"
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
s.close
n2=dt.datetime.now()
diff=(n2-n1)
print diff.seconds
e(0)
```

Server code:

```
#server.py
import socket               # Import socket module
import sys, time
e=sys.exit
#s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = %s                 # Reserve a port for your service.
print port
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
f = open('/tmp/testfile_%d.png','wb')
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
i=0
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    c.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    #c.setNoDelay(True)
    #c.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_CORK, 1)
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    print "Receiving..."
    if netcat:
        netcat.write('netcat from file writer')
    i=0
    l = c.recv(1024*1024)

    while (l):
        f.write(l)

        l = c.recv(1024*1024)
        i +=1
        if 0 and i>20:
            f.close()
            e(0)
    f.close()
    
    #c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)  
    s.close()
    print "Done Receiving"
    e(0)
e(0)
```

When I run it in 2 jobs in parallel (different ports/shells) performance drops 50%.

Alternatively when I use sftp in parallel:

```
time sftp user@server://tmp/testfile.gz.gz test0.gz&
time sftp user@server://tmp/testfile.gz.gz test1.gz&
time sftp user@server://tmp/testfile.gz.gz test2.gz&
```

elapsed time does not change for 2 or 3 parallel jobs.

Comment: Are you using the same physical Interface? Maybe you're hitting your bandwith limit...

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you just trying to understand your results? At a glance (and if I understand your reporting correctly), I'd say you are finding the crossover point between CPU-bound (because sftp/scp doing additional work to encrypt) and I/O-bound (network is saturated so that becomes the limiting factor instead of CPU).